# Firefox on Windows 11 - Open File with Adobe is not keeping the file in temp

Tags: firefox, windows-11

I just switched to Windows 11 and Firefox have a strange behaviour. When a download of a PDF starts it is configured that it will ask me what to do. So in general I use open with Adobe PDF Viewer. This also works. But the file is anyway in my Download-Folder. I was used that it will be saved in the temp folder %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp and then also deleted after a while. If I want a file saved for a longer time I save it explicitly to a location I want to have it.

Any idea what is wrong in the Windows 11 or Firefox (currently 98.0.1)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behavior.

I tried to re-install the version 97 of firefox on Windows 11 plateform and it use again the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp when I open a PDF in Acrobat.

It's seems to be related to the new last Firefox version, but not to Windows 11 plateform.

I try to find a way to get the "old" behavior using the %USERPROFILE% "Temp" folder rather than the "Download" folder set in the firefox settings withe the last 91.0.1 version of Firefox ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, but I'm using Windows 10 with Firefox version 101.0.1

The way I fixed this is by going to *about:config* in Firefox and changing "browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel" to **false**.

Your PDFs should now appear in your %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp folder.